# VisualForce - conditional html tags

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to apply a different style to the first element in a list.

I am currently attempting to use a counter to apply the `li` with a `class` only when `cnt==0` but I cannot include `<` `>` brackets in an `OutputText` tag. Is there any way to escape the brackets or insert the `class` into an `<li>` tag using a condition?

I know this could be done after the fact using JavaScript but I'd rather avoid it.

```
<apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" /> 
<apex:repeat value="{!items}" var="item" >
    <!-- only render the class if it is the first element -->
    <apex:OutputText value="<li class="activeLI">" rendered="{!cnt==0}" />
    <apex:OutputText value="<li>" rendered="{!cnt!=0}" />        

        <img src="{!$Resource[item.Image__c]}" width="85" height="90"/>
    </li>
    <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visualforce is strict, every element must have an opening and closing tag or must be self-closing. When compiled, Visualforce will complain as it will only see the closing "li" tag and not the conditional opening "li" tag, one solution is to make the class name a variable as follows:

```
<apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" />
<apex:variable var="class" value=""/>
<apex:repeat value="{!items}" var="item" >
  <apex:variable var="class" value="activeLI" rendered="{!cnt==0}"/>
  <apex:variable var="class" value="" rendered="{!cnt!=0}"/>
    <li class="{!class}">
      ...
    </li>
  <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Great idea!  I made a small modification by removing the counter all-together, setting `class` to `activeLI` when defining it then emptying the value after it is used the first time.  Many thanks for the idea.

Comment: Thanks, and nice improvement there!

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using a CSS selector? Here's an example on how to style the first element of  a list.

```
<style>
ul.myList > li:first-child {color : red}
</style>

<ul class="myList">
  <li>this is red</li>
  <li>this has default formatting</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `<apex:dataList>`? I think it may accomplish what you're looking to do.